# Replacing all special characters with a Regular Expression

Tags: regex, internationalization

I am trying to replace all German special characters in a Regular Expression.
The Characters are  ä ö ü ß

Comment: @SilentGhost: The "typical" replacement for those chars would be "ae", "oe", "ue" and "ss" or "sz", respectively. @basit74: Aren't you going to handle the uppercase Umlauts too?

Comment: Oh, and another question: Which programming language are we talking about?

Comment: then regex is probably not the best tool here

Comment: Do you have a regular expression containing those characters or do you wish to use a regular expression to replace those characters in a string? If it is the latter, regular expression is used for pattern matching, not replacement. If you need to replace something, we need to know what tools you wish to use to perform that replacement.

Comment: I hope basit comes back soon to give us some clues.

Comment: Can you put this in the form of a question, or would you like moral support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do all 4 (or 7) replacements with a single regexp. It's fairly easy, thought, to do it with 4 (or 7) regexps.

**Update**

Additionally, as Mic has indicated, regexps can be part of the solution but need to be part of some kind of replacing mechanism. More input needed here.

Answer (score 0):

[Regxr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) can help you write one.
Try this:

RegExp: /\bäöüß\b/gi

pattern: \bäöüß\b

There are a number of ways to apply the actual replacement depending on the language or situation you are in.

Answer (score 0):

```
/ä/ae/
```

If Carl is correct about what replacements you're talking about, that'll do; but regexs are not really required here, it can be done with a simple string function/methods.

Of course, for each character you'd need to write new regex.

If you wanted to replace them all with a single character, e.g., a question mark (`?`), you could use the following regex:

```
/[äöüß]/?/ig
```

Comment: Like Mic and I said, it depends on the language. We need to know what language is being used here.

Comment: What depends on the language? Ability to write regex that'll do some intelligent replacement?

Comment: No, the exact code for replacement. The question was *how to* and that can't be exactly posted without more info.

Comment: I think *how* is secondary to *what*. OP hasn't given any indication of what is he actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace each of those characters with a different character, you'll need four regexes:

```
/ä/X1/
/ö/X2/
/ü/X3/
/ß/X4/
```

where X1-X4 are the four replacement characters

OR, if you want to replace any occurrences of those characters with a single character:

```
/[äöüß]/X/
```

where X is the replacement character.

The exact regex syntax may different, depending on the programming language.